# Can't render on WSL2 + react

Tags: reactjs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I have a project on my windows machine that works correctly.
I recently installed wsl2 to try, and copied the project folder there (\$wsl folder).
I run npm install, and react-app.
Then when I run npm start, I have the browser that opens on localhost:3000 like usual, but nothing happens, it's a blank page. And I have no errors in my IDE (intelliJ)

Any suggestions and help ?

Comment: Check your browser console?

Comment: What about errors in the browser console?

Comment: I have this : crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.